# Spring Specification dynamic query join

Tags: spring, spring-data, specifications

I have two entity:

```
@Entity
public class User{
    @Id
    private String id;
    ...
    private String username;
    private String customerId;
}

public class Customer{
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
}
```

How can I create dynamic query just like:

```
select * from user where username='...';
select * from user u left join customer c o u.customerId=c.id where c.name='...';
```

and without `@OneToOne`?

Comment: No way without defining entity relations - `@OneToOne` in your case. It's not SQL

Comment: Thanks for your apply. I tend to avoid foreign key.But now in this case, it seems that I must use `@OneToOne`.